# Is there widely agreed naming convention to differentiate between entities and value objects?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design

On couple DDD applications I worked on, we had sometimes both Entity and Value Object corresponding to same concept. Value objects were particularly useful when retrieving large lists for read-only use.

To differentiate between the two, we appended `Info` to the Value Object class. Therefore, `Customer` was an Entity, and `CustomerInfo` was Value Object.

Is it a commont thing to do in DDD? Or is there any different common convention? Or maybe same concepts should not be modelled as Entity and Value Object at the same time?

Comment: `CustomerInfo` seems like a [read-model](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/).

Comment: @eulerfx - Great info thanks. Yes, read model is really what I am looking at here. You upped my understanding a bit there.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any common convention, everyone names it as they see fit. Personally I don't care if an object is an entity or value object. It doesn't change the way I code things. Also, probably there aren't many cases where same concept can be modelled as both entity and value object at the same time. Even in different bounded contexts, a Product is still an entity even if in BC1 it has only an id and name and in BC2 it has all the details.

The domain tells you which should be an entity and which isn't, but again, IMO the difference is insignificant when using the object. What matter is that the object be properly designed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that using a prefix/sufix like that is against DDD

You should focus in naming everything as you speak to your domain expert. Maybe it is just my personal preference, but I would not be comfortable speaking all the time using a predefined set of prefixes all the time. I would rather speak the terms freely and hide the implementation detail.

There is one exception though, and that is the word "Event" since in that case you need to explain domain experts that an Event is something that happens. You should not explain to them what is the difference between an entity and a value object.

That being said, I personally use inheritance to highlight value objects from entities. Their equality functions are different and also only the later needs an ID field.

Comment: That's a valid comment about the language, I was thinking that too

Comment: Prefixes, suffixes, annotations, and namespace separation are different strategies that help make your code *architecturally evident*. That's definitely a good practice, at least in the source code.